# Return an array of different types in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, linq, typescript, asynchronous, array-filter

In TypeScript 2.5.3 I've a bunch of selenium WebElements which are links. I need to get their targets in an array of strings. Caming from C# I would use Linq with `.Select()` which itself returns a list of the return type from the selector. In Typescript this doesn't seem to work so nicely:

```
    let categoryLinkElements = await this.driver.findElements(By.css('ul li a'));
    let categoryLinks = categoryLinkElements.filter(async linkElement => await linkElement.getAttribute('href'));
```

`categoryLinkElements` is an array of `WebElement`. And `linkElement.getAttribute('href')` returns `Promise<string>`. Cause `await` is used, I would expect that `categoryLinks` is an array of strings, like the same behavior of `List.Select()` in C#. Instead, `categoryLinks` is `WebElement[]`.

Why? And how can I get the correct return value?

Comment: you are using filter.. if the href's is what you wnat you should use map. now you are just filtering out the elements that have href falsy.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.filter` seems wrong here, instead it should be used to return the same value than the input array, but with some filter condition. Instead `Array.map` is the correct equivalent of `List.Select` in C#.

The following works as expected:

```
let categoryLinks = categoryLinkElements.map(async linkElement => await linkElement.getAttribute('href'));
```

As a beginner of Typescript and Javascript, this seems a stupid question afterwards... sorry :/

Comment: Beware here that `categoryLinks` will be an array of `Promise<string>` not of `string`;

Comment: @JKillian is correct, you should add a call to reduce